# Fantasy book I read in 2005; title contained "tower", children go through TVs to fantasy world

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a book about four children who go to their uncle's house and find a bunch of TVs unplugged in the attic. They are able to go through the TVs into an alternate fantasy world, where they appear in a prison and meet an old man. Some scenes and facts I remember:

1. Pool/well with spiral stairs leading down to a door at the bottom of the pool.
2. Castle island in a lake
3. Father time personified along with a sleeping army
4. Main character having to navigate tunnels with red and blue lights acting as guides
5. One of the 4 children was a little girl
6. Pretty sure the title had the word tower in it!

P.S. It's not Narnia for sure

Any help would be appreciated! I've been looking for years!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*The Tower of Geburah*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/192977.The_Tower_of_Geburah). It's the third book in the "[Archives of Anthropos](https://www.goodreads.com/series/69777-archives-of-anthropos)" series (but the first one published).

[image: Book Cover]

> One moment Wesley, Kurt and Lisa are poking around in their uncle's attic. The next moment they have stepped into the magical world of Anthropos, where their help is needed to free a king and defeat the powers of evil....

It sounds like it's only three children, but there is a girl, there are televisions, and the cover shows a castle island in a lake.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response! I've been looking for ages!

Comment: Not at all. Sometimes all it takes is asking. :)